# Mapping and displaying in twig template

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Hi I am trying to create such mapping

```
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_users", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UsersEmailAddresses", mappedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_users", referencedColumnName="users_id")
     */
    private $email;
```

and

```
class UsersEmailAddresses
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_users_email_adresses", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var \Users
     * @ORM\Column(name="users_id")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Users")
     */
    private $users;
```

And when I am trying to display many emails with one user like

```
<td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
<td><ul>
{% for e in entity.email %}
     <li>{{ e.email }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul></td>
```

im getting error like `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined index: users in /var/www/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1575") in /var/www/symfony/src/Test/UserBundle/Resources/views/Users/index.html.twig at line 22`

22 line is the `for` loop

Comment: updated my answer - anything unclear or needs more explanations? otherwise accept please :)

Comment: dont forget to update your schema with doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: you removed the accept from the answer - anything not working ? how can i help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mapping error here. Documentation: [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html), [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html) and [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html)

- referencedColumname references to the ID field of your related entity.
- name is the name of the extra column holding the foreign key to be created-
- referencedColumnName is the foreign key of the related entity.
- you define ManyToOne on the owning **and** OneToMany on the inverse side...
- *don't use OneToMany on both sides* !!
- the joinColumn definition has to be on your owning side ( aka the one which uses inversedBy ).

---

**IF** you had a many-to-one relation of users ... to one address ... **which you dont**.. 
The JoinColum would be on your user entity ( aka. owning side of bi-directional association )

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_users", referencedColumnName="users_id")
 */
```

.. should be ...

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_users", referencedColumnName="id_users_email_adresses")
 */
```

**But ... In your case ...**

One user shall have many adresses ... address will be the owning side of your bi-directional one-to-many relation.

**User**

oneToMany , mappedBy

**Address**

ManyToOne, inversedBy (+ JoinColumn)

---

**Tip:**

you can ommit the @JoinColumn completely as it will be auto-generated...

Entity names should usually be singular ...

Why these complicated id columns in your database ...isnt it enough to have a table user with a column id ?

Comment: I don't know why, I always use structur like `id`+_table_name